# RHEL7 yum update dependency issue

Tags: rhel7

On RHEL 7.5, while executing yum update -y I m getting below dependency issues

Could you please help me to resolve these issue ?

I tried below commands, but no luck

```
 using --skip-broken
 rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
 package-cleanup --dupes
 package-cleanup --cleandupes


    ---> Package opensm-libs.x86_64 0:3.3.20-2.el7 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: opensm-libs(x86-64) = 3.3.20-2.el7 for package: opensm-devel-3.3.20-2.el7.x86_64
---> Package sg3_utils-libs.i686 0:1.37-12.el7 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: sg3_utils-libs = 1.37-12.el7 for package: sg3_utils-devel-1.37-12.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: sg3_utils-libs = 1.37-12.el7 for package: sg3_utils-devel-1.37-12.el7.i686
---> Package sg3_utils-libs.x86_64 0:1.37-12.el7 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: sg3_utils-libs = 1.37-12.el7 for package: sg3_utils-devel-1.37-12.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: sg3_utils-libs = 1.37-12.el7 for package: sg3_utils-devel-1.37-12.el7.i686
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: glibc-static-2.17-260.0.9.el7.x86_64 (@ol7_optional_latest)
           Requires: glibc-devel = 2.17-260.0.9.el7
           Removing: glibc-devel-2.17-260.0.9.el7.i686 (@7_latest)
               glibc-devel = 2.17-260.0.9.el7
           Updated By: glibc-devel-2.17-260.0.15.el7_6.5.i686 (ol7_latest)
               glibc-devel = 2.17-260.0.15.el7_6.5
           Available: glibc-devel-2.17-222.el7.i686 (ol7_latest)
               glibc-devel = 2.17-222.el7
           Available: glibc-devel-2.17-222.0.7.el7.i686 (ol7_latest)
               glibc-devel = 2.17-222.0.7.el7
           Available: glibc-devel-2.17-260.0.15.el7_6.3.i686 (ol7_latest)
               glibc-devel = 2.17-260.0.15.el7_6.3
           Available: glibc-devel-2.17-260.0.15.el7_6.4.i686 (ol7_latest)
               glibc-devel = 2.17-260.0.15.el7_6.4

Error: Package: opensm-devel-3.3.20-2.el7.x86_64 (@base)
           Requires: opensm-libs(x86-64) = 3.3.20-2.el7
           Removing: opensm-libs-3.3.20-2.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda/7.5)
               opensm-libs(x86-64) = 3.3.20-2.el7
           Updated By: opensm-libs-3.3.20-3.el7.x86_64 (ol7_latest)
               opensm-libs(x86-64) = 3.3.20-3.el7
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```